# Bluemix Deploy Behaviors - Declared Services

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops

I have the following `manifest.yml` file for a WAR file deployment to Liberty on Cloud Foundry-based Bluemix.  When I use the deploy stage from the pipeline to my own workspace, the declared services and service bindings to the app from my manifest file are ignored.  However, when using the `Deploy to Bluemix` button, the dependent services and bindings are created.

How can I force the deploy stage to create and bind services if they don't exist in the space when NOT using "Deploy to Bluemix" but simply using the deploy stage?

```
---
declared-services:
  tuck-cloudant-cloudantNoSQLDB:
    label: cloudantNoSQLDB
    plan: Shared
applications:
- services:
  - tuck-cloudant-cloudantNoSQLDB
- name: HelloWorldTuck4
  path: HelloWorld.war
```

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: The 'Deploy to Bluemix' feature has some special magic that reads the Manifest file and binds services defined in them. Do not believe it is possible outside this feature to bind services during the deploy stage.

Answer (score 3):

The service bindings in the file `manifest.yml` are IBM extensions to the Cloud Foundry standard (see the [Deploy to Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/deploy_button.html)) which are hopefully incorporated. However, at this time only the special deployment processing of the `Deploy to Bluemix` button will take care of that declared services section and will provision the services for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I suspected it was a deploy to bluemix only option.

Comment: @data_henrik is this still the case? Also any idea if it works with the `bluemixcloudfoundry` provider for Travis CI? Can't find anything related to it online

Comment: No idea on your Travis CI question. I just followed the provided links and the declared services are not yet in CF.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can script the service creation in the pipeline.
There is even a way to make it occur with a Deploy to Bluemix button, using a pipeline.yml file in your sample repo: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/sharetextpipelines.html

See an example there:
https://github.com/hmagph/sample-java-cloudant

Comment: Excellent!  I didn't think about scripting this out with CF.  I'll look at the examples.

Answer (score 0):

The declared services are specific to `Deploy to Bluemix`.  You can, however, run pretty much any cf cli command you want in the deploy stage.  You should be able to do a `cf create-service ...` or a `cf bind-service ...`.  This would have to be done manually, adding lines to the deploy script.